# unhandledRejection: Error: NEXT_REDIRECT on trying to redirect to another page in Next's 13

Tags: typescript, redirect, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to check if a user is logged in and redirect them to the login page if not.

My code:

```
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from '../src/firebaseConfig'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

// ...

export default async function Home() {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (!user) {
      redirect('/login')
    }
  })
  // ...
```

I get this error from that:

```
error - node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js (47:18) @ getRedirectError
error - unhandledRejection: Error: NEXT_REDIRECT
    at getRedirectError (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js:40:19)
    at redirect (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js:46:11)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/layout.tsx:29:70)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/totp-e47c784e.js:2684:26) {
  digest: 'NEXT_REDIRECT;replace;/login'
}
```

On another branch where I have yet to implement auth checking I have the following code in the same place and it works without any problems.

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {
  redirect("/home");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please take the [tour]. There's a reason you don't see [resolved] on any other questions here.